# C# Regular expressions, get left and right words separated by a comma

Tags: c#

I have following input string
string `str = "a,b,c,d";`

Output expected in groups, like (get the left and right word of each comma)

```
[group0 : a b]       [group1 : b c]       [group2 : c d]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
string str = "a,b,c,d";
string[] parts = str.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length-1; i++)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parts[i] + " " + parts[i+1]);
```

BTW, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

**Edit:**
For those who have any concern about this solution, [here's demo](http://ideone.com/RREFov).

Comment: I do not think he had tried anything. There are many ways to do this, the simpliest and quicker the one you presented, IMO.

Comment: I have tried this pattern string pattern = @"(?<first_name>\w+),(?<last_name>\w+)";    This pattern provided groups ad (a b) and (c d)

Comment: @ThunderGr You are right. Honestly, if I had to do something like that I'd reread my code. I hate solutions like this.

Comment: @user1852580 I would not go with `Regex` here. There might be more or less than 4 elements separated by comma and `Regex` is not always very flexible.

Comment: Quite late, but I am pretty sure the loop should be: for (int i=0; i < parts.Length - *2*; i++). When at parts.Length-1 parts[i+1] will raise an unhandled "Index out of Range" exception...

Comment: hahaha. You are right! The first time I had seen the code(about a year ago) I understood it correctly. This time I miscalculated the *<* -1. Sorry. Really, very stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

You can match against a single group and iterate over matches using this regex:

```
([^,]+),([^,]+)
```

So, first group will be left word and second group will be right word in each match.

Comment: I have tried this pattern string pattern = @"(?<first_name>\w+),(?<last_name>\w+)";          Your pattern also provides the same result as what i have tries : (a b) and (c d)

Comment: You can use look aheads, but you can not find overlaping matches using regex. You'd better use @PLB's way.